# If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, is it true that $\sigma(n^2)/q^k \mid n^2$?

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility, alternative-proof, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

**Question**

> If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, is it true that $\sigma(n^2)/q^k \mid n^2$?

**Motivation**

Note that is easy to prove that
$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}.$$
Indeed, this follows directly from the observation that $\gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k))=1$.

In particular,
$$\dfrac{n^2}{\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}}=\dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{2},$$
which does appear to show that $\sigma(n^2)/q^k \mid n^2$, since
$$\sigma(q^k) \equiv k + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod 4.$$

> Does this proof suffice?

I would be interested in seeing other (alternative) proofs for the same result.

Comment: Your proof looks correct to me. It seems that yours is the "simplest" proof for the claim.

Comment: Thanks for affirming, @mathlove! I will go ahead and accept it if you write out your last comment as an actual answer. =)

Comment: I converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks correct to me.

It seems that yours is the "simplest" proof for the claim.